# How do I write a tooltip for this list of cities?

Tags: geography

```
cityList = Sort[CityData[{All, "California"}]]    
distanceToSanFrancisco[s_] := 
 QuantityMagnitude[
  TravelDistance[cityList[[859]], Interpreter["City"][s]]]
(* table1 takes a while to run on my system*)
table1 = Table[{cityList[[k]], 
    distanceToSanFrancisco[cityList[[k]]]}, {k, Length[cityList]}];
citiesWithin[range_] := 
 Module[{s = {}}, 
  Do[If[table1[[k, 2]] <= range, s = Join[s, {cityList[[k]]}]], {k, 
    Length[cityList]}]; s] (*This lists all cities in California that are within `range` of San Francisco.*)
radius = 25;
tolerance = 0.05;
a1 = GeoDisk[
   QuantityMagnitude[
    LatitudeLongitude[Interpreter["City"]["San Francisco"]]],
   Quantity[radius, "Miles"]];
a3 =
  Complement[
   citiesWithin[radius*(1 + tolerance)],
   citiesWithin[radius*(1 - tolerance)]
   ];
Table[a3[[k]] -> distanceToSanFrancisco[a3[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[a3]}]
Show[a2, GeoListPlot[a3, PlotMarkers -> Point], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

This last one is what I want the tooltips on.  For the red points around San Francisco, ideally I would like to get just city name.  TIA

Answer (score 1):

Using [`GeoLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoLabels.html) vice [`Tooltips`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltips.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cityList = Sort[CityData[{All, "California"}]];

Length@cityList

(* 1096 *)

distanceToSanFrancisco[s_] := 
   QuantityMagnitude[TravelDistance[
       Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", 
            "UnitedStates"}], s]]

table1 = {#, distanceToSanFrancisco[#]} & /@ cityList;

radius = 25;
tolerance = 0.05;

a3 = Select[table1, 
   radius*(1 - tolerance) <= #[[2]] <= radius*(1 + tolerance) &];

GeoListPlot[(First /@ a3),
 PlotMarkers -> Point,
 GeoLabels -> True,
 GeoRangePadding -> Scaled[0.2],
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]